Возможно ли использовать пинги OkHttp в качестве heart-beating протокола STOMP?
Мне необходимо реализовать клиентскую часть протокола STOMP (под Android). Я использую OkHttp и его фичи с веб-сокетами для этого. Мне также нужно реализовать heart-beating, которые являются частью протокола STOMP.
Интересует, возможно ли в качестве heart-beating использовать пинги из библиотеки OkHttp, установив .pingInterval() в OkHttpClient? Если, например, сервер также реализует этот протокол на основе веб-сокетов и готов принимать веб-сокетовские пинги в качестве heart-beat.
